# Set up Unison for use over internet with dynamic ip

Tags: server, internet, unison

I have two desktop pcs with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit installed on both the machines. I want to sync both ways the files between the two computers (office and home) using unison over internet without using LAN. My ISP has provided only a dynamic IP address not a static IP address. How to install and use Unison in such a scenario?

Comment: Just curious, if your two machines are on your local network, why do you want to set up Unison to sync over the internet rather than locally?

Comment: Those are  not on local network.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a third machine as a server that your home and office computers have ssh access to and storage access to (see [star topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_network)). Since your ISP doesn't provide you with a static IP, you'll probably need to use a third-party service (something like [rsync.net](http://rsync.net/)).

Actual instructions for setting this up would be a bit too general and lengthy to be a good answer on this site, so for info on that see the following references:

- The [Unison Tag Wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/unison/info) on this site
- A good [guide to setting up Unison](http://www.pgbovine.net/unison_guide.htm) by Philip Guo
- The [Unison Manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html)